# json_encode return null and block code below

Tags: php, json, slim

I got stuck with a json_encode() problem in PHP.
The simple function below is trying to send the response data to an API call.

```
function makeResponseOK($data) {
    if($data) $response['data'] = $data;
    $response['meta'] = ['msg' => 'OK', 'status' => 200];
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    return json_encode($response, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
}
```

It works perfectly fine on my MAC. However, when I tried to deploy it on my Ubuntu Server, json_encode() does not work at all and any line below json_encode() is neglected.
For example:

```
echo 'crazy';
echo json_encode($data);
echo 'crazy';
```

will only output one "crazy" to me. I also tried:

```
echo json_last_error_msg();
echo json_last_error();
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

but none of them give me any result, not even a number...

I have completely no idea what is going on there and I really appreciate if you could help me with it!!!

In addition: My Ubuntu Server's PHP version is 5.5.3 and I am using SLIM framework, idiorm.(Though I don't think it is related...)

Comment: Have you verified that json is installed? I believe it should be listed under `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` or `php -i`

Comment: `json_encode` only returns `string` or `false`. It does not, to my knowledge, return `null`. Please turn on *all* error reporting (put `error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script) and try it again.

Comment: Apparently, you have php 5.5 on your ubuntu server. PHP5.5 doesn't have JSON in the box because of license issues.

Comment: @Brett I see. That's the problem. I didn't noticed the license issues for PHP 5.5... That's crazy

Comment: Thanks @AxelPAL. I checked the conflict reason... It's a funny little story...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to check if `json_encode` is actually available on your server. I know it should be there by default, but I ran into some servers where that function was not available.

```
if (function_exists('json_encode')) {
    echo 'Yes';
} else {
    echo 'No';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have just used `json` use `json_encode` instead

```
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
echo json_encode($arr); // Here!
echo json_last_error_msg();
echo json_last_error();
```

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo...I used it correctly in my code though:)